# API or framework for handling transactions

Tags: api

I am developing a JSP web (based on Java) and I would like to let users send the altcoins to my servers wallet. I need something what would monitor if the coins (DOGE/BTC etc.) has arrived and just after that let the users do something.

Is there anything like this? I am new here and maybe it is broad but let me explain better if you need.

I mean something like this: http://bitcoinj.github.io/getting-started

but not only for BTC also for other coins.

Comment: Have you reviewed this document?
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29#Java
outlines how to communicate with bitcoin server directly, MOST altcoin use a replica of this interface to provide API access.  There are however some altcoins which use their own unique system.

Answer (score 1):

for example you can subscribe to unconfirmed transaction on the [blockchain websocket](https://blockchain.info/it/api/api_websocket) and monitor when your addresses appear in the flow.